# High Chart Legends rotation not working on IE 10,11 when select document mode 8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, highcharts

Rotation is working fine if we select edge mode of Internet Explorer 10 or 11 as shown in image

[image: correct image]

taken from High Chart Demo Charts While if we select Document mode 8 in IE 10 or IE 11 the rotation is not working as shown in image

[image: wrong image]

I have analysed the same the Filter rotation properties are not working fine afterwards IE 10 and found a solution that its working fine if we Enable the Render legacy filters as shown in [image]

But this will fix the problem for only one system. We need to solve the issue without select this option on individual system

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug, reported here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1711